# Is there a way to find percentage difference between 2 different days for a specific group?

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the percentage difference between 2 days for a specific group in my table.

I need percentage change of column [Group] with the field 'FUND' between days `20190731` and `20190628` by using the column Value. In my example should be `-75%`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
select prd, grp, 100.0 * (sum(end_value) - sum(start_value)) / sum(start_value)
from
    (
    select prd, grp,
        (case when date = "20190731" then val else 0 end) as end_value,
        (case when date = "20190628" then val else 0 end) as start_value
    from table1
    ) as t
group by prd, grp
```

Comment: That's great but I would like this to be dynamic so each month to do the same calculation after I have declare the end date as a reference point

Comment: @John You can create a stored procedure with the above sql code in it that takes the two dates as arguments and returns the resulting rows.